# Confusion regarding the proof of the theorem "An integral domain $R$ with ACCP is FD(Factorization Domain)."

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Actually I got a confusion when I am learning the proof the theorem "*An integral domain $R$ with ACCP is FD(Factorization Domain)."*
The begining of the proof of the theorem goes as follows-
Suppose on contrary, $D$, which is an ID with ACCP, is not FD. Then $\exists$ a non-zero, non-unit element $a\in R$ such that a does not have factorization. **Then $a$ is not irreducible.** ...(and so on)
My question is **why the non-zero, non-unit element $a \in R$, which does not have factorization, is not irreducible**?

Can anybody clear my confusions?

Answer (score 1):

What is the prime factorization of a prime number?

Comment: Lmao. $\qquad{}$

Comment: @D_S, here factorization means **factorization of a non-zero, non-unit element into irreducibles**. SO my question is- if an non zero, non-unit element does not satisfy the condition(I have mentioned in bolded), then why it will be a not irreducible element(i.e. "reducible")?

Comment: By definition, an element $x$ is *factorizable* if there exist irreducible elements $p_1, ... , p_s$ such that $x = p_1 \cdots p_s$.  What happens if $s = 1$?